# Can't connect Docker Desktop Kubernetes (Windows) services to local Postgres db via Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am not able to connect a dockerized Spring Boot API managed by Kubernetes via Docker Desktop (Windows) to a local instance of Postgres. Error is as follows:

> ```sh
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgres-db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
> ```

Up until trying to connect to a local DB, everything has been working fine (external clients can connect to pods via Ingress, pods can communicate with each other, etc).

I think somewhere my configuration is off here.

**ConfigMap**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-12-27T18:38:34Z
  name: test-docker-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "810136"
  uid: 352c4572-eb35-11e7-887b-42010a8002b8
data:
  spring_datasource_platform: postgres
  spring_datasource_url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/sandbox
  spring_datasource_username: postgres
  spring_datasource_password: password
  spring_jpa_properties_hibernate_dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

**Service**

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-db-svc
spec: 
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: kubernetes.docker.internal
  ports:
  - port: 5432
```

In my hosts file, "kubernetes.docker.internal" is mapped to 127.0.0.1

**Deployment**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tester
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tester
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tester
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tester
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: test-spring-boot
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PLATFORM
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: test-docker-config
              key: spring_datasource_platform
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: test-docker-config
              key: spring_datasource_url
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: test-docker-config
              key: spring_datasource_username
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: test-docker-config
              key: spring_datasource_password
        - name: SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: test-docker-config
              key: spring_jpa_properties_hibernate_dialect
```

**Spring Boot application.properties**

```sh
spring.datasource.platform=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PLATFORM:postgres}
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sandbox}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:password}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT:org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes with Docker runs in the same docker VM, so I'm assuming the `/etc/hosts` file that you are referring to is the one on your Windows machine.

I'm also assuming that you ran Postgres exposing `5432` with something like this:

```sh
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

First, `127.0.0.1` is not going to work because docker just exposes the ports on the IP address if the VM.

Secondly, Kubernetes will not able able to find `kubernetes.docker.internal` because the pods use [`CoreDNS`](https://coredns.io/plugins/kubernetes/) to resolve and it has no idea about that domain.

I suggest you do this:

- Don't use `kubernetes.docker.internal` as it's already used by docker for its own purpose. Use something like `mypostgres.local`
- Get the IP address of your docker VM. Run `ping docker.local` or look under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts for something like this:

  ```
  Added by Docker Desktop
  10.xx.xx.xx host.docker.internal
  ```

  or look at the output from `ipconfig /all` and find the IP from the docker desktop VM.
- Use [`hostAliases`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/#adding-additional-entries-with-hostaliases) in your podSpec, so that the `/etc/hosts` file is actually modified in your pod.

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: tester
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: tester
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: tester
      spec:
        hostAliases:
        - ip: "10.xx.xx.xx" # The IP of your VM
          hostnames:
          - "mypostgres.local"
        containers:
        - name: tester
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: test-spring-boot
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
  ```
- Don't use an `ExternalName` service as those work only with CoreDNS. If you want the `ExternalName` service to work you will have to modify your [`CoreDNS`](https://coredns.io/plugins/kubernetes/) config so that it hardcodes the entry for `mypostgres.local`

Note: Another option is just to run Postgresql in Kubernetes and expose it using a regular [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) service.

Comment: Not sure how connected these other actions were but I also had to add "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" to my pg_hba.conf and also increase the memory in my deployment to 300Mi.